# Admobs ad only shows on the simulator

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, admob

I've having issues with creating an admob ad which will be shown on the simulator and the device. At the moment i't will only show on the simulator. Here i get an ad which say: PUBLISHER TEST AD.

I've searched for sometime, but cant find an solution

Why wont it show on the device as well?

```
- (void)viewDidLoad

{
self.bannerView = [[GADBannerView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0.0, self.view.frame.size.height-50, GAD_SIZE_320x50.width, GAD_SIZE_320x50.height)];

self.bannerView.adUnitID = myAdUnitID;
self.bannerView.delegate = self;
[self.bannerView setRootViewController:self];
[self.view addSubview:self.bannerView];
[self.bannerView loadRequest:[self createRequest]];


[self.navigationController.tabBarController.tabBar setHidden:YES];

}

-(GADRequest *)createRequest {
     GADRequest *request = [GADRequest request];
     request.testDevices = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:GAD_SIMULATOR_ID, nil];
     return request;
 }

 -(void)adViewDidReceiveAd:(GADBannerView *)adView {
     NSLog(@"Ad Received");
     [UIView animateWithDuration:1.0 animations:^{

         adView.frame = CGRectMake(0.0, self.view.frame.size.height-50, adView.frame.size.width, adView.frame.size.height);


     }];

 }


 -(void)adView:(GADBannerView *)view didFailToReceiveAdWithError:(GADRequestError *)error {
     NSLog(@"error due to: %@", [error localizedFailureReason]);
 }
```

Comment: where are you ? admob only visible in device on foreign areas .

Comment: request.testDevices = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:GAD_SIMULATOR_ID, nil]; remove this line and then try it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Admobs ad only shows on the simulator
```

Because You Added `GAD_SIMULATOR_ID` in this line of code so it showing only testing ads on simulator.

```
[NSArray arrayWithObjects:GAD_SIMULATOR_ID, nil];
```

So my opinion is you can test on device as if you add your `device id` in this array.So every time when you open this app this will show you test add and as soon possible if add available on `Google Admob` this will show you the ad and start showing Impression on your `Admob` account.

Comment: So what do i need to change to not get a test ad and make it show on the device?

Comment: add your device id with this array `[NSArray arrayWithObjects:GAD_SIMULATOR_ID,@"your_device_id" nil];
`

Comment: So if i want every device to see this ad i need to programmatically find the actual device id?

Comment: no dude you just add your id and then test it if ok remove your id so whenever user install your app it will request to google for add if ad available this will show on the device. For testing purpose you can add uuid so everytime ad will come.